# disposable.dispose() NullPointerException

Tags: android, rx-java2

I'm trying to fetch data from service using Retrofit2 and RxJava2.
The request is being sent every 5 seconds by means of `repeatWhen`.

Method `start()` and `stop()` are called on UI events.
The problem is raised when method `stop()` is being called, it leads to NPE (see comment). But `disposable` must be valid ref after `start()` is called. If I use commented `try-catch` block `disposable.dispose()` works ok. Don't understand what's the difference between these approaches.

Any thoughts?

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = MyFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private Disposable disposable;

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        start();
    }

    public void start() {
        disposable = ServiceApi.getInstance().getItemsRequest()
                .map(ItemsResponse::getItems)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .repeatWhen(f -> f.delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableSubscriber<List<Item>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        Log.d(TAG, "In onCompleted()");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "In onError()");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(List<Item> items) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "In onNext()");
                        Log.d(TAG, "Items: " + items);
                    }
                });
        Log.d(TAG, "Disposable created: " + disposable);

        // if dispose this way it's OK
        /*try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(15);
            Log.d(TAG, "Calling dispose: " + disposable);
            disposable.dispose();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
    }

    public void stop() {
        disposable.dispose(); // NPE here
    }

}
```

Comment: where did you call stop ??

Comment: From host Activity `fragment.stop()`on btn click

Comment: did it trigger after the transaction ?? or before the creation of fragment it got triggered ??

Comment: post your activity code please

Comment: Sorry guys, I missed stupid error while working with FragmentPagerAdager within host activity. Just figured out the cause.

Answer (score 1):

For you scenario its better to use `CompositeDisposable`. Dispose `CompositeDisposable` on Fragment `onDestroy`

```
CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

 public void addToCompositeDisposable( Disposable disposable){
   if (compositeDisposable != null) {
     compositeDisposable.add(disposable);
   }
 }

  @Override public void onDestroy() {
   super.onDestroy();

   if (compositeDisposable != null && !compositeDisposable.isDisposed()) {
       compositeDisposable.dispose();
   }
}
```

In `start` method add the `disposable` to `compositeDisposable`

```
addToCompositeDisposable(disposable);
```

Comment: `Log.d(TAG, "Disposable created: " + disposable);` this line wont trigger NPE .

Comment: `ServiceApi.getInstance().getItemsRequest()` this is enough to init the disposable/observable !! its not necessary to fir the calkback to come to init it !!

Comment: disposable `initialization` is on the **UI thread** !! , the callback is observed in mainThread , and its **SUBSCRIBED** in `io()` thread . No chance it will cause NPE in the logged line !!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I made a stupid error while working with viewpager. This topic isn't worth time.